# To remove product review tab in product page in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, frontend, review, tabs, product-page

I need to remove review tab in product page.Please suggest a solution
**catalog_product_view.xml** in my custom module

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove= "true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">XXX_YYYY::review.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.review.popup" template="XXX_YYYY::popup.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="custom.product.review.form" as="custom.review_form" template="XXX_YYYY::form.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Your magento version..? 2.2.0 ?

Comment: My version is magento 2.2.0

Comment: Hello Jayashree I could not understand your target. If you are about to removing block then your first action works well. What are you willing to do?

Answer (score 10):

Can try following XML, for remove Review Tab on Product page

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to remove all reviews tabs on product page is to extend the Magento_Catalog folder from desing and create your own, building a child theme.

And inside layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Add this:

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.review.form" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
```

Tested and working on Magento 2.3 as well.

Answer (score 3):

Override `catalog_product_view.xml` and append into `<body>` tag following ;

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: I have overriderd product.info.review

Comment: see the updated post

Comment: It removes the tab, But failed to save the review in my custom template

Comment: I just needed to override 'reviews.tab'

Comment: @00-BBB please ask a separate question for it, as if I answer it here other users would not be able to find it. You can link  the question here.

Comment: its should be <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>
tried this and worked for me.